# Django queryset optimization - Aggregate from one table and count from another table

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-queryset

We have a key-value datastore, defined by the following models :

**models.py**

```
#Table with millions of entries
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group) 

# Table with few entries
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

# Table with hundreds of entries
class ResultType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()

# Huge table with billions of entries
class Result(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='gotten_results')
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, related_name='given_results')
    result_type = models.ForeignKey(ResultType, related_name='type_results')
    value = models.CharField()
```

So what I want to achieve is to get for a given list of 'Person', the programs that gives at least one result and count it at program level.

For the moment, what I did is the following :

```
def my_function(given_group):
    persons = Person.objects.filter(group=given_group)
    programs = Program.objects.all()

    given_results = {}
    for program in programs :
        given_results[program.name] = 0

        for person in persons :
            # if the program gave at least one result to the person
            if Result.objects.filter(program=program, person=person).exists() :
                given_results[program.name] += 1
            else:
                continue

    return given_results
```

That is the easiest way to do it (2sec thinking) but if my given_group contains one million of person, that is a terrible way to do it.

The other solution that came to my mind is to use select_related/prefetch_related but I can't figure how to use them with the exists() or the LIMIT equivalent [:1]

Does anybody have a good suggestion to achieve the same results with few requests ?

**SOLUTION**

Daniel's answer put me on the right track, so here is the solution :

```
given_results = Result.objects.filter(person__group=given_group).values('program__program_name').annotate(total=Count('person', distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to be querying the related tables at all, since you don't actually want the data. What you want is an aggregation that counts the values. So:

```
from django.db.models import Count
given_results =  ResultValue.objects.filter(person=person).values('program__name').annotate(total=Count('*'))
```

That gives you a list of dicts in the form `{'program__name': 'foo', 'total': 100000}`, but it's fairly trivial to convert that into a single dict if that's what you need.

Comment: That's almost it, in fact the question is not 'How many results did the program give?' but 'How many times did the program give results ?' so if a program has given 10 results for 1 person I want to count it as 1.